# Getting login year data with the 'last' command on linux

Tags: linux, logging, last

On Solaris, there the command 'fwtmp' provide the year information from the wtmp logs.  For example:

```
host # /usr/lib/acct/fwtmp < /var/adm/wtmpx > tmp_wtmpx_file
host # head -1 tmp_wtmpx_file
user123 sshd 1258 7 0000 0000 1226072918 230489 0 29 host123.desktop.ourhost.com Fri Nov  7 09:48:38 2008
```

On Linux, the 'last' outputs the data without the year information, and I don't seem to be able to find a utility similar to 'fwtmp' on Linux to add the year data.  The 'lastlog' command includes year in the output, but only looks up the users that are in the passwd file (not against ldap or other user databases by default).  Is there a utility on Linux that will output the year along with the other data from 'last'?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
man last
...
       -F     Print full login and logout times and dates.
...
```

So, use `last -F`

Comment: It's not available in RHEL5/CentOS5, though.

Comment: That's why.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

On RHEL5, `last -F` isn't available.

If you want to have only the `last` informations from a specific year, you need to use `last -t`.

ex:

- `last -t 20140101000000` show everything before 2014.
- `last -t 20130101000000` show everything before 2013.

if you run a diff between the 2 commands, you can have only informations for 2013.

See [Getting "year" with last command on Red Hat 5](https://serverfault.com/questions/642723/getting-year-with-last-command-on-red-hat-5) for more informations if needed.